# elastic search query for geo points distance

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i wanna get resources that are in delivery radius by customer point.
my mapping is like below:

```
 "restaurantPoint"       => [
 "type" => "geo_point"
 ],
 "deliveryRadius"        => [
 "type" => "float"
 ]
```

and a sample data as below:

```
`"restaurantPoint": "35.73701996471125,51.409086138010025",
"deliveryRadius": 1`
```

so, each restaurant has a point and a delivery radius in km, in the other hand we know user point.
in query i wanna get restaurants that can deliver food to user location.
i must check if distance between restaurant point and user point are less than equal to restaurant delivery radius.

for example, if distance between user and restaurant is 1 km and restaurant delivery radius is 2 km we can select that.

[elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html) document is not complete to find out solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i used script:

```
GET development-restaurants/restaurants/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
        "must" : {
            "script" : {
                "script" : {
                    "source": "doc['restaurantPoint'].arcDistance(35.73702, 51.40909) <= doc['deliveryRadius'].value",
                    "lang": "painless"
                 }
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```